# I get errors, any suggestions?

Tags: java

When compiling this java program, I get errors like cannot find symbol... any suggestions?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class joel001
{
    public int d;


// find the smallest number of an array
public static int small(int a[])  
{

    int smallest=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<smallest)
        {
            smallest=a[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}

// subtract the smallest number of an array from all its elements
public static int[] sub(int a[],int d)
{
    this.d=d;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
    {    
        a[i]=a[i]-d;
    }
    return a;
}

// count the array's non zero elements
public static int count(int a[])
{
    int countn=0;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
        {
            if(a[i]!=0)
            {   
            countn=countn+1;
            }   
        }
    return countn;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int b,c,z,k=1;
    int a[]=new int[1000];

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);   
    b=s.nextInt();           //input
    for(i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        a[i]=s.nextInt();
    }
    while(k==1)
    {
        z=count(a);
        if(z==0)
        {
            break;
        }
    System.out.println(z);
    c=small(a);
    a=sub(a,c);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just what symbols does it claim to not be able to find?  Did you verify that you had actually defined them?

Comment: you should also not reference the non-static variable d in static int[] sub, among other things.

Comment: I recommend you the usage of an IDE - it should show you the actual locations of your errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, the length of an array is `arr.length`, *not* `arr.length()`.

Secondly, in `sub()`, there *is* no `this` because it's a static function.

Thirdly, in `main()`, you need to declare `i` before trying to use it.

That will take care of all your *compile-time* errors. Run-time, or logic, errors are something you need to learn to fix in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring all your methods of joel001 as static.  Static methods are not related to an instance or object of the joel001 class.  You need to research OOP before you continue.

Try something like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class joel001
{
    public int d;


// find the smallest number of an array
public int small(int a[])
{

    int smallest=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<smallest)
        {
            smallest=a[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}

// subtract the smallest number of an array from all its elements
public int[] sub(int a[],int d)
{
    this.d=d;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
    {    
        a[i]=a[i]-d;
    }
    return a;
}

// count the array's non zero elements
public int count(int a[])
{
    int countn=0;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
        {
            if(a[i]!=0)
            {   
            countn=countn+1;
            }   
        }
    return countn;
}

public void main2() {
    int b,c,z,k=1;
    int a[]=new int[1000];

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);   
    b=s.nextInt();           //input
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        a[i]=s.nextInt();
    }
    while(k==1)
    {
        z=count(a);
        if(z==0)
        {
            break;
        }
    System.out.println(z);
    c=small(a);
    a=sub(a,c);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
  joel001 obj = new joel001();
  obj.main2();
}
}
```

Comment: Good first practical step: deleting `static`, but recommending "OOP reaearch" seems overkill to me, it would probably suffice to "read some Java beginner's tutorials".